# Simpliest Dockerfile ever to untar: file not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile, tar

I'm a freshly new docker user. I spend a lot of time on a error, the Dockerfile is really short and easy, but I'm not able to solve this.

I'm trying to download a tar file, and to unarchive it

Here is my Dockerfile (each tries was not in the Dockerfile as the same time, I put them together for the sake of simplicity)

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# 1st try
ADD https://download.gnome.org/sources/glib/2.52/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz /tmp/
RUN ls -lah /tmp/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz
ADD /tmp/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz /tmp

# 2nd try
ADD https://download.gnome.org/sources/glib/2.52/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz /tmp/
RUN ls -lah /tmp/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz
RUN tar -C /tmp/ -xf /tmp/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz

# 3rd try
WORKDIR /tmp/
RUN wget https://download.gnome.org/sources/glib/2.52/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz
RUN ls -lah glib-2.52.1.tar.xz
RUN tar -xf glib-2.52.1.tar.xz

# 4th try
RUN wget https://download.gnome.org/sources/glib/2.52/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz -O /tmp/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz
RUN ls -lah /tmp/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz
ADD /tmp/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz /tmp

# 5th try
RUN wget https://download.gnome.org/sources/glib/2.52/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz -O /tmp/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz
RUN ls -lah /tmp/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz
RUN tar -C /tmp/ -xf /tmp/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz
```

I tried every possible thing to make this file beign downloaded and to unarchive it.

The error occured only on the last step command (unarchive, step 4).

I basically tried the 5th try on my computer and it works:

```
$> wget https://download.gnome.org/sources/glib/2.52/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz -O /tmp/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz
$> tar -C /tmp/ -xf /tmp/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz
$> ls /tmp/glib*
glib-2.52.1 glib-2.52.1.tar.xz
```

here is the output when I used tar:

```
$> sudo docker build -t gtk --no-cache .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/5 : FROM ubuntu:latest
 ---> 0ef2e08ed3fa
Step 2/5 : ADD https://download.gnome.org/sources/glib/2.52/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz /tmp/
Downloading [==================================================>]  7.676MB/7.676MB
 ---> caa91f90fdca
Removing intermediate container 2952ba563006
Step 3/5 : RUN ls -lah /tmp/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz
 ---> Running in 9570826c1437
-rw------- 1 root root 7.4M Apr  8 06:24 /tmp/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz
 ---> 4335ecb50e2a
Removing intermediate container 9570826c1437
Step 4/5 : RUN tar -C /tmp/ -xf /tmp/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz
 ---> Running in e5a847dd0427
tar (child): xz: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
The command '/bin/sh -c tar -C /tmp/ -xf /tmp/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

here is the output when I used ADD:

```
[...] # same output

Step 4/5 : ADD /tmp/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz /tmp/
lstat tmp/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz: no such file or directory
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A good way to debug a Dockerfile is to use `docker run -it myimage bash` and try repeating the `RUN` instructions at the terminal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Always read the output carefully for hints:

```
tar (child): xz: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
```

You are missing the `xz-utils` package in the image which is required to handle xz archives. Try:

```
RUN apt-get install xz-utils && tar -C /tmp/ -xf /tmp/glib-2.52.1.tar.xz
```